# Memory Leak Found by Leaks Instrument (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments, xcode-instruments

I am having trouble understanding the leaks found by the Leaks instrument right after build.  Is this being caused by my own code or a library?

Let me know if you need more information, and thanks!

[image]

Comment: libSystem.dylib... looks like its out of your hands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libSystem.dylib` is a system library. If you run your app on a device you shouldn't encounter this leak anymore. 
The leak is related to the way the simulator works.

Comment: you're right - I ran on my device and no leaks.  i spent so much time on trying to figure it out too -- argh.  thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

looks like it some system code and it's probably allocating a permanent memory chunk. It's a very small allocation and there's only two of them. I don't think its a concern--all apps "leak" some memory.

what to watch out for:

- many repeated small allocations... For example: an NSString created and leaked every time you adjust a volume slider.
- larger chunks that are meant to be used once and thrown away. For example, an image loaded for a window background that isn't released when the window is closed

Comment: I disagree. There's no such thing as "all apps leak some memory". Otherwise what would be the need for a good memory management or ARC? The leak mentioned by the OP is the result of some internal issues of the Xcode simulator coming back since Xcode 4.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is leaks may show things as leaks when they're actually not. And practically speaking, if your app leaks 64 bytes it's not worth worrying about.